# change url for modules in Yii2

Tags: yii2

Is there an easy way to change the default url for a module? I have created an `Admin` module but I don't want it to reside at `/admin` as that is easy to guess and I'd like to host it at a more obscure path like `/c3ntgu33sthis` but don't want to create a module called `c3ntgu33sthis`, plus I'd like to change the url once in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring your module you can set any name for it you like and change it later on.

I assume you have got something like:

```
'modules' => [
    // ...
    'admin' => [
        'class' => 'module\namespace\for\Admin'
    ],
],
```

Change it to:

```
'modules' => [
    // ...
    'c3ntgu33sthis' => [
        'class' => 'module\namespace\for\Admin'
    ],
],
```